# when statement to exclude specified folders and files from showing an extension command in a context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my VS Code extension, I have some commands I wish to have available in the explorer view, and want their availability to be based on what's selected.  Let's say I open a folder in VS Code, and the folder has the following:

```
/a
/a/1.txt
/a/2.txt

/b
/b/3.txt
/b/4.txt

/c
/c/5.txt
/c/6.txt
```

I wish for a command to be present when folder "c" or anything within it is selected, but not a or b.

Also, I want the logic to *exclude* specific folders (and their contents), not *include* specific folders (eg I want the logic to be, "the command is available to everything **except** a or b")

In my extension's `activate()` function, I have:

```
  vscode.commands.executeCommand(
    'setContext',
    'ext.list',
    [
      'a',
      'b'
    ]
  );
```

And in my `package.json`, I have:

```
{
  "command": "samplecommand",
  "when": "resourceFilename in ext.list"
}
```

When I run this, I find that the command is available when I have folders a or b selected, but not when I have any of the items within it selected (like `a/1.txt`).  I tried using `a/*`, `a/.*`, and `a/*.*` but I haven't found anything which works.

So, when using "resourceFilename in", does it support regex?  Or does it only do exact string matching?  How can I get a positive match when either the folder or one of the items within the folder is selected?

OK, next, I want to exclude the command anyway, and when I tried:

```
{
  "command": "samplecommand",
  "when": "!(resourceFilename in ext.list)"
}
```

...or:

```
{
  "command": "samplecommand",
  "when": "resourceFilename !in ext.list"
}
```

...the command doesn't appear for either a, b, or c.  Is it possible to test for when the filename is ***not*** in the list?  It appears this is always evaluating to false.

So, TL;DR, I'd like to filter commands in the Explorer view, and have then not appear for specific folders, and items within the folder.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

You have

```
"contributes": {
   "menus": {
     "explorer/context": [
       {
         "command": "ext.samplecommand",
         "when": "resourceFilename in ext.list"
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

and an `'ext.list', [ 'a', 'b' ]`

> When I run this, I find that the command is available when I have
> folders a or b selected, but not when I have any of the items within
> it selected (like `a/1.txt`). I tried using `a/*`, `a/.*`, and `a/*.*` but I
> haven't found anything which works.

But `resourceFilename` resolves to something like `a` for a folder and `myFile.js` for a file.  So `"resourceFilename in ext.list"` works as you expect for folders, since `resourceFilename` resolves to `a` or `b` if they are selected.  But it won't help for files since `resourceFilename` does not resolve to the folder name but to a file name.

To get the menu item to show for both folders and their included files you could do this:

```
"menus": {
  "explorer/context": [
    {
      "when": "resourceFilename in ext.list || !explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceDirname =~ /(\\/|\\\\)(bundle|concat)$/",
      "command": "ext.samplecommand"
    }
  ]
}
```

where `(bundle|concat)` represent `dirname`'s you want the files of which to be **included**.

Which answers your question about regex's being supported in `when` clauses.  Yes, see [key-value when clause operator](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#keyvalue-when-clause-operator):

> There is a key-value pair match operator for when clauses. The
> expression `key =~ value` treats the right-hand side as a regular
> expression to match against the left-hand side.

The above uses `resourceDirname =~ /(\\/|\\\\)(bundle|concat)$`

that will check the `resourceDirname` against **ending** in `\bundle` or `/bundle` or `\concat` or `/concat`  (with lots of escapes before the back or forward slashes).

---

Now, to get to your final destination - filtering the menu to **not** show commands for specific folders and files.

I do not think there is a way to negate the `resourceFilename in ext.list` "operator".  I seem to recall a github issue on it but I can't find it now.

> **Update**: the `not in` operator is being added to vscode v1.70. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660631/836330.  So that might solve your last negation question in a much cleaner fashion.

But there is another way since we can use a regex as we saw above in a `when` clause.  But it has to be a little trickier because we are trying to exclude certain folders and files.  Try this:

```
"menus": {
  "explorer/context": [
    {
      "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourcePath =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\\/)(bundle|concat))$/ || !explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceDirname =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\\/)(bundle|concat))$/",
      "command": "ext.samplecommand"
    }
  ]
},
```

---

- `explorerResourceIsFolder && resourcePath =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\\/)(bundle|concat))$`

When the selected resource is a folder, check its `resourcePath` which will be its full file path ending in the folder name.

So `resourcePath =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\\/)(bundle|concat))$` uses a negative lookbehind to match folder paths that do **not** end with a folder named `bundle` or `concat` in this example (your `a` and `b`).

- `!explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceDirname =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\\/)(bundle|concat))$/`

When the selected resource is a file and not a folder, check its `resourceDirname` which will be its full file path ending in the folder name.

So like above this uses a negative lookbehind to match only files with `dirnames` that are not `bundle` or `concat`.

---

So in summary, since the `resourceFilename in ext.list` type of construct cannot be negated you have to use the `key =~ value` type of `when` clause and be sure to compare it to the right resource name.  And "negate" that by using a regex negative lookaround of some sort.

---

To figure this out the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command is **invaluable**.  It allows you to see what context keys are available for explorer folders and files and those keys' values.  That is how I found that `resourcePath` was best for folders and `resourceDirname` for files - since in both cases the full paths ended with the folder name.

See [Inspect Context Keys utility documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility).

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was a great tip about using `Developer: Inspect Context Keys`

Comment: Also, just an update, this seems to work for what I'm looking for

 ```{
    "command": "samplecommand",
    "when": "resourcePath =~ /^((?!\/(foo|bar)).)*$/"
},```