# Context when clause with not in operator

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Following is my command:

```
{
  "command": "myextension.mycommand",
  "when": "resourceFilename in resources",
  "group": "%my.group%@1"
}
```

`resources` is an array of string. This when clause works; but I would like to do a `not in` instead.

VSCode Extension Docs does not list any `not in` operator - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts

How can I perform a `not in` clause?

Comment: There is not a `not in` or `!(resourceFilename in resources)` type of operator built-in - I know I have seen it requested in the issues.  Here it is: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131819

Comment: how dynamic is the content of `resources`

Comment: the current parser of the when clause is a very simple string split on `&&` and `||` (no `()` support), but adding a `not-in` operator should not be a problem, they already have `==` and `!=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for `not in` in a `when` condition has just landed in VS Code.  It should be in Insiders v1.70 very soon and then in Stable v1.70 early August, 2022.

See [Support "not in" context key expression](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/5acd9508c913b1d0ce3243f056c3cb039bac6938)..

So you be able to do this soon:

```
"when": "resourceFilename not in resources",
```

---

---

Soon to be previously:

Since there is no `not in` type of character you will have to use a more verbose `when` clause.  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/70444134/836330 where to exclude two folders (`bundle` and `concat`) you could use a `when` clause like this:

`"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourcePath =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\/)(bundle|concat))$/ || !explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceDirname =~ /.*?(?<!(\\\\|\\/)(bundle|concat))$/"`

You can see the general form involves a negative lookahead for an alternation of the folders you want to exclude.  The code above would exclude the command from appearing for both folders and files within those folders.

The `(?<!(\\\\|\\/)` part covers forward and back slashes for different operating systems.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_conditional-operators for another example of the conditional operator `=~` which takes a regex on the right side of the operator so you can create a "negation" there.